# ExecutorService shutdown

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I am confused about the javadoc of [ExecutorService#shutdown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) method. Aren't these contradictory statements?

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are
>   executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. This method does not wait
>   for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use
>   awaitTermination to do that.

If it can orderly shutdown previously submitted tasks, then how can't it wait for them to complete execution?

Comment: The comment means the previous tasks will not be discarded. Not that they will be executed immediately. Use `awaitTermination()` for that.

Comment: The routine returns almost immediately instead of waiting for all the tasks to finish.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means that the method returns immediately in the thread that you call it in, but tasks that haven't yet been executed might still be running, in other threads.

If you want your program to wait until the tasks that had been submitted previously have finished, you have to call `awaitTermination` after calling `shutdown`.

Comment: Exactly, it simple separates two concerns. There might be some case in which you want to shutdown without waiting.

Comment: Can I imagine calling awaitTermination() to be something like calling .join() on the ExecutorService instance ?  If I do not call awaitTermination(), in that case the main thread (or caller thread, to be precise) continues along with the ExecutorService threads concurrently.  If I call awaitTermination(), the main thread will stop execution until the ExecutorService threads are done.  Please confirm whether my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 6):

It means that the tasks will run to completion, but this method will return immediately, without waiting for that to happen.

So, to cleanly shutdown your executor without killing any tasks, you would do:

```
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);
```

Alternatively, if you just want to stop your executor as quickly as possible, use `shutdownNow()`.